# Формирование привязки данных для класса

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Доброго времени суток.
Столкнулся с проблемой. При привязке массива (int[] и т.д.) к ItemsControl.ItemsSource, массив привязывается и отображается но значение вводимые пользователем не возвращаются в массив. Я так предполагаю это потому что UI не знает куда данные записывать так как не знает с каким элементом сейчас происходит работа. Пришлось написать не большой ViewModel:

```
internal class AbstractArrayView : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Array Context {
        get { return (Array)GetValue(ContextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContextProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("Context", typeof(Array), typeof(ArrayViewModel<>), new UIPropertyMetadata((o, e) => {

          }));

    #region PropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void Change(string Property) {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Property));
    }
    #endregion
}

internal class ArrayViewModel<T> : AbstractArrayView
{
    #region Property
    public List<Item<T>> Items {
        get {
            List<Item<T>> temp = new List<Item<T>>();
            if (Context != null) {
                for(int i =0; i< Context.Length; i++) {
                    Item<T> item = new Item<T>(i, (T)(Context as T[])[i]);
                    item.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler((s, e) => {
                        if (Context != null) {
                            (Context as T[])[(s as Item<T>).Index] = (s as Item<T>).Value;
                            Change(string.Empty);
                        }
                    });
                    temp.Add(item);
                }
            }
            return temp;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Собственно данная модель правильно формирует привязку и записывает все изменения от UI. 
Проблема в следующем. Все привязки происходят при формировании шаблона:

```
        FrameworkElementFactory Property = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ItemsControl));
        Type AType = property.PropertyType.GetElementType();
        var view = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ArrayViewModel<>).MakeGenericType(AType), null);
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(view as DependencyObject, AbstractArrayView.ContextProperty, "//не понятно что здесь писать");
        Property.SetValue(ItemsControl.DataContextProperty, view);
```

Помогите правильно создать экземпляр привязки.
На данный момент:
[image: UI]

То что внутри:
[image: Модель]

Изменяем значение:
[image: Ui2]

Данные не изменились: 
[image: Результат]

Comment: Почему не используете `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: нет смысла в использовании ObservableCollection, так как данная реализация и так работает. Вопрос в другом.

Comment: Вопрос здесь: BindingOperations.SetBinding(view as DependencyObject, AbstractArrayView.ContextProperty, "//не понятно что здесь писать");

Comment: А где вы создаете экземпляр `Binding`?

Comment: его нет там так как не знаю что писать

Comment: `new Binding(...) { ... }`

Comment: хорошо, так: new Binding(".") { Source = //здесь что? };

Comment: Покажите что вы хотите в итоге получить, как этим пользоваться?

Comment: Добавил описание

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в привязке к value type. Каждый элемент коллекции работает с копией значения, меняет её, но это не отображается на оригинале.

Поместите ваши `int`-значения в класс-обёртку.

---

Простой пример:

Обёртка:

```
class ArrayWrapper<T>
{
    public class Box
    {
        internal T[] array;
        internal int index;
        public T Value { get => array[index]; set => array[index] = value; }
    }

    public Box[] Data { get; }

    public ArrayWrapper(T[] array)
    {
        Data = Enumerable.Range(0, array.Length)
                         .Select(n => new Box() { array = array, index = n })
                         .ToArray();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Click="OnClick">Inspect</Button>
</Grid>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ArrayWrapper<int>(data);
    }

    int[] data = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Join(", ", data));
    }
}
```

Результат:

[image: анимация]

---

По поводу того, почему не работает ваш пример, причиной может быть то, что:

1. Вы неправильно определили DependencyProperty `Context`. Вы указали тип `typeof(ArrayViewModel<>)`, а нужно `AbstractArrayView`.
2. Вы объявили, но не реализовали `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
3. Ваше свойство `Items` на каждом `get` пересоздаёт список снова.

(ну и вы не привели код `Item`'а)

Comment: Я это и сделал! Выше описан этот класс. У меня проблема при создании привязки моего массив к обертке из FrameworkElementFactory

Comment: @TomDugger: Попробуйте мой пример, он работает.

Comment: спору нет - работает. Но все же вопрос в формировании привязки

Comment: @TomDugger: Дописал ответ. А почему вы формируете шаблон в code-behind, а не через XAML? Вы создаёте сами себе проблемы, смотрите, какой неизящный получается код.

Comment: Это своеобразный конструктор UI на основе класса. Сам проверяет какой тип данных и для него формирует шаблон.

Comment: @TomDugger: Как-то слишком сложно, ну и кроме того, зачем вам шаблон? Третьим аргументом `BindingOperations.SetBinding` нужен, понятно, `Binding`.

Comment: Для управления объектом класса.

Comment: Это понятно, просто хотел отметить это место

Comment: @TomDugger: А зачем для этого шаблон? Ну наклепайте `UserControl`'ов для нужных типов и вставляйте в StackPanel.

Comment: Для простых типов - это бы сработало, но если к примеру свойство типа MyClass[] - не возможно предугадать какой шаблон нужен

Comment: @TomDugger: Ну так тоже не проблема, спускайтесь рекурсивно вниз. Для массива `ItemsControl`, для элементов рекурсивно их нужный UI-контрол. Непонятно, зачем вам строить Template.

Comment: Для удобства. По факту в приложении будет только один Label в Content которого помещается экземпляр объекта. Далее WPF сом собирает UI для объекта и его свойств.

Comment: В принципе система рекурсивно проходит по каждому свойству и составляет шаблон для него (если его нет). Далее происходит отображение

Comment: @TomDugger: Честно говоря, не вижу удобства. Ручное составление шаблонов — очень неприятное занятие. Из-за этого и баги. Вы бы лучше составляли контрол.

Comment: Как раз таки ручного ничего нет

Comment: @TomDugger: Ну, вы создаёте шаблоны вручную, кодом, а не через XAML. Составлять их через XAML намного проще.

Comment: Тут вопрос не в простоте написания шаблонов, а в их функциональных возможностях. Мне требуется разработать функционал, благодаря которому на основе пользовательского класса сформируется UI.

Comment: @TomDugger: Ну да, но можно же генерировать прямо сразу контрол?

Comment: Хорошо. Сразу через xaml собирать Ui - правильно бы было, но если к примеру используется пользовательский класс в котором определено свойство типа другого пользовательского класса. При этом я наверняка не знаю будет такое свойство в классе или нет. Я создаю функционал который позволит для любого класса собрать UI.

Comment: Вопрос закрыт. Придумал реализацию через специальный контрол унаследованный от ItemsControl